VMs of family B
I'm currently evaluating various VM sizes and families for deployment in my production environment, where I primarily run Power Automate and Chrome for automation tasks.
I've been using VMs from the B-series family, but I've noticed that they become quite slow after some time. I would like to understand better what "burstable" means and how the credits these VMs generate and consume automatically work. This concept is still quite confusing to me.
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I was trying to choose a cheap size of BM, but I am noticing the slowness of the series B VM. As I asked, what is exacly this Burstable?
Is there another family more prepared to be in production environment?

From the vms tag description: "Note: This tag should not, as a rule, be used for Virtual Machines (VMs)." How does your question relate to the VMS family of operating systems: OpenVMS, VAX/VMS, and VAX-11/VMS?
